# ¿Cómo hacer una validación personalizada en Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, validación

Muy buenas!

Actualmente tengo un problema con una validación personalizada que estoy haciendo.

Tengo este método:

```
validateInstagram(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const value = control.value;
      let valid = false;

      if (!value) {
        return null;
      }

      let match = value.match(keys.ctrl_instagram_pattern);

      if(match === null || match![0] !== value) valid = false; else valid = true;

      console.log(valid ? { instaValid: true } : null);
      
      return valid ? { instaValid: true } : null;
    }
  }
```

Que se encarga de validar que una cuenta de instagram está bien construida o no mediante una expresión regular.

Cómo se ve en el return, si la cuenta es válida, retorna un objeto, si no, retorna *null*.

El problema es que cuando pasa la validación, no me la pasa bien a pesar de que veo claramente que el resultado es el que creo que es el bueno, me explico.

Cuando lo ejecuto, mirando por consola los valores, veo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me está devolviendo *null* y el estado de ese controlador es *VALID*, cuando entiendo que debería de ser al revés.

Siguiendo está lógica, si pongo en el *return* lo siguiente:

```
return valid ? null : { instaValid: true };
```

Se comporta como debería.

Cómo puedo arreglar esto?

Comment: esto está mal escrito `if(match === null || match![0] !== value)` sobra `!` en `match[0]`. Dudo que sea este el error

Comment: No, ese no es el error, en la última actualización de angular (creo que fue por esto), metieron este tipo de validaciones, te obliga a poner *!* o *?* para controlar los posibles valores nulos.

Comment: ahh muy bien. Gracias por la info

Answer (score 0):

Según me han comentado, el error está en que lo estoy haciendo al revés, las funciones de validación devuelven un objeto cuando falla y devuelve un valor *null* cuando no.

Por lo tanto, el código de la función debería de ser así:

```
  validateInstagram(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const value = control.value;
      let valid = false;

      if (!value) {
        return null;
      }

      let match = value.match(keys.ctrl_instagram_pattern);

      if(match === null || match![0] !== value) valid = false; else valid = true;
      
      return valid ? null : { instaValid: false };
    }
  }
```

Yo pensaba que funcionaban al revés.

Comment: Así es. Cuando se genera en un error se retorna un objeto que contiene suficiente información para identificar el problema, de lo contrario, no se retorna nada o null.